# How to access database for custom files

Tags: zend-framework2

Apart from controller, forms, models and views, I want to create a file which contains some classes for common functionality. eg common.php

So do I need to make other connection file for this custom file of mine or there any other way to use zend database files (config/local.php and config/global.php)

And under which folder should I create this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong concept. Create a `YourNamespace\Stdlib`-Library with Classes that contain common functionality. Those classes would then later be injected with the dependencies they need. For example:

```
getServiceConfig() {
    return array( 'factories' => array(
        'stdlib-dbstuff' => function ($sm) {
            $dbStuff = new \YourNamespace\Stdlib\DbStuff();
            $dbStuff->setAdapter($sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'));
            return $dbStuff;
        }
    ));
}
```

See classes below the namespace [`Zend\Stdlib`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/tree/master/library/Zend/Stdlib) for some examples ;)

To use your `Stdlib` simply call the classes you need from the `ServiceManager`. Alternatively you could skip the `ServiceManager` and simply inject the dependencies on Controller-Level (which somewhat sucks, that's not a controllers responsibility).

```
$dbStuff = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('stdlib-dbstuff');
// alternatively
$adapter = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
$dbStuff = new \YourNamespace\Stdlib\DbStuff();
$dbStuff->setAdapter($adapter);
```