# Zend Framework 2 How to access a class in Controller?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have created a folder with classess in it. I am trying to access the return of a class in that folder in my controller.

Thanks in advance

The model class **GetUserPersonalData** and its located here:

E:\wamp\www\ZendEbayApp\module\Application\src\Application\models

**my controllers are located here:**

E:\wamp\www\ZendEbayApp\module\Application\src\Application\Controller

**BackendUserAdministrationController.php**

```
    <?php

namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

class BackendUserAdministrationController extends AbstractActionController {

    public function indexAction() {
        $this->layout('layout/BackendAdministrationLayout');
    }

    public function AddAdditionalUserAcountsAction() {
        $this->layout('layout/BackendAdministrationLayout');

        $GetUserPersonalDataClassObject = new \Application\models\GetUserPersonalDataClass();
        $theoutputarray = $GetUserPersonalDataClassObject->GetUserPersonalDatafunction();
        echo $theoutputarray[1];
    }

    public function AddCompanyDetailAction() {
        $this->layout('layout/BackendAdministrationLayout');
    }

    public function AddUserAccountAction() {
        $this->layout('layout/BackendAdministrationLayout');
    }

    public function AddUserPersonalAction() {
        $this->layout('layout/BackendAdministrationLayout');
    }

    public function AddUserPlanDetailAction() {
        $this->layout('layout/BackendAdministrationLayout');
    }

    public function AddUserPreferencesAction() {
        $this->layout('layout/BackendAdministrationLayout');
    }

    public function AddUserTransactionsAction() {
        $this->layout('layout/BackendAdministrationLayout');
    }

}
```

**GetUserPersonalData.php**

```
    <?php

class GetUserPersonalDataClass {

    public function GetUserPersonalDatafunction() {

        $GetUserPersonalDataArray = array();

        $OpenedUserPersonalFile = fopen("E:/wamp/www/ZendEbayApp/data/usersinformation/userPersonal.txt", "r");
        while (!feof($OpenedUserPersonalFile)) {
            $OpenedUserPersonalFileSingleRow = fgets($OpenedUserPersonalFile);

            array_push($GetUserPersonalDataArray, "$OpenedUserPersonalFileSingleRow");
        }
        fclose($OpenedUserPersonalFile);

        return $GetUserPersonalDataArray;
    }

}

$GetUserPersonalDataClassObject = new GetUserPersonalDataClass();
$theoutputarray =  $GetUserPersonalDataClassObject->GetUserPersonalDatafunction();

echo $theoutputarray[1];
?>
```

When i debug BackendUserAdministrationController.php with betbeans it also says:

```
        E:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php.exe E:\wamp\www\ZendEbayApp\module\Application\src\Application\Controller\BackendUserAdministrationController.php

    Fatal error: Class 'Application\Controller\AbstractActionController' not found in E:\wamp\www\ZendEbayApp\module\Application\src\Application\Controller\BackendUserAdministrationController.php on line 7

    Call Stack:
        0.0013     130104   1. {main}() E:\wamp\www\ZendEbayApp\module\Application\src\Application\Controller\BackendUserAdministrationController.php:0

    PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Application\Controller\AbstractActionController' not found in E:\wamp\www\ZendEbayApp\module\Application\src\Application\Controller\BackendUserAdministrationController.php on line 7
    PHP Stack trace:
    PHP   1. {main}() E:\wamp\www\ZendEbayApp\module\Application\src\Application\Controller\BackendUserAdministrationController.php:0
    Done.
```

Comment: Although you've provided netbeans debug info, you haven't actually described the problem you're having with the code you've posted. Are you getting any error messages when you navigate to your controller action? What's it doing that it shouldn't be, or what's it not doing that you were expecting?

Comment: I "belive" the error message has nothing to do with my problem. I just want to know how to call the instance of the class in modles/GetUserPersonalData.php into the controller. When call the instance in same class and echo it, it works fine but when put it in the controller i just get a black sceen. I think the path to the class is wrong but i dont know what the path is. Thanks

Comment: This is how im calling the instance and getting the data from the class. $GetUserPersonalDataClassObject = new GetUserPersonalDataClass();
$theoutputarray =  $GetUserPersonalDataClassObject->GetUserPersonalDatafunction();
echo $theoutputarray[1];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class doesn't appear to have a namespace, which might explain the problem, try adding one

```
<?php
// add this line to your model class
namespace Application\models;

class GetUserPersonalDataClass
{
    // <snipped/>
}
```

Comment: Hi, I added the namespace and it did not work, but i think the problem may "also" be somewhere else. When i add my snipped to call the instence of the class then my screen goes blank and i dont see anything(not even the layout). By the way i made that folder with the models, it did not come with the zend framework 2 skeleton application. I can place that folder somewhere else as well.

Comment: I have also tryied calling the class GetUserPersonalDataClass(); in BackendUserAdministrationController like this but it does not work.  I just get blank screen $GetUserPersonalDataClassObject = new Application\models\GetUserPersonalDataClass();

Answer (score 0):

Instead of class, create a library file,
 Maybe this can help:

[How to access database for custom files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15896557/how-to-access-database-for-custom-files)